Where do I define the Custom Input Schema in EventGrid?
When creating an Event Subscriptiion in an Azure Storage Account...

...there is an option for a Custom Input Schema.
.
Question is: Where do I define this custom schema?
Goal: When a blob is uploaded to a Storage Container, a queue message is generated with certain custom values. This queue message then triggers an Azure Function.


Question is: Where do I define this custom schema?

According to this MS-Document,

When you create an Event Grid subscription to a Storage account, you are subscribing to a system topic.The events that are sent to the subscription are generated by Azure Storage and are related to the storage account and its contents


Note: For example, a system topic may represent all blob events or only blob created and blob deleted events published for a specific storage account.


System topics cannot be deleted or modified, and their schemas are fixed and cannot be changed. custom event schema is only for custom topics and not for system topics like storage account for more information.

Reference:

Azure Event Grid event schema - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn
Map custom field to Azure Event Grid schema - Azure Event Grid | Microsoft Learn

